# Syntax of DecimalFormatting Doubles

Tags: java, format, double, decimalformat

I'm new to java and I've hit a sort of 'syntax learning curve' here. I was wondering how I would get the Doubles in my program i.e. "rate", to format to "#.00"?

I assume I'd have to use "DecimalFormat" to do this but I'm not quite sure how to go about using it to achieve what I want in this situation:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());

while (st.hasMoreTokens())
{   
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    hours = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());   // Converts number of hours to double
    rate = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());  // Converts rate to integer

    totalCost += (hours * rate);
    System.out.println("Rate = £" + rate + "\t" + "Hours = " + hours);
}
```

Unfortunately I'm still at the stage where the Oracle Documentation is 95% incomprehensible  to me so any helpful insights here would be most welcome :)

EDIT: printout currently looks like this...

```
 Rate = £8.0
```

Should look like this:

```
 Rate = £8.00
```

Comment: What does the program print out when it is executed?  What do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
System.out.println("Rate = E" + df.format(rate) + "\t" + "Hours = " + hours);
```

Comment: As simple as that. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You defined the `DecimalFormat`, but never used it in the printing.

Display it like this:

```
System.out.println("Rate = £" + df.format(rate) + "\t" + "Hours = " + hours);
```